# Character escape sequence for @ symbol

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to display a printed document with an '@' sign on it, however, there is always an extra '@' sign that I can't get rid of. I tried escape sequence using backslashes and double '@' sign, but it's still there. See image:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            String secondValue = item[i, 0] + "            " +item[i, 1] + " @"+item[i, 2] +"                     "+ item[i, 3];
            graphic.DrawString(secondValue, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
            offset = offset + 35;        
        }
```

How can I get rid of that extra @ sign below the list?

Comment: include your code of grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the nth row contains nulls.  Try changing the loop condition from `i <= n` to `i < n`.

Comment: I didn't notice that. You saved my life sir, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@` is in your text template. You have to include it only when you are printing an actual item.

Comment: What do you mean sir? The image actually is the print preview.

Comment: `item[n, 0]` and `item[n, 2]` are blank, as you have realized.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** escape sequence available for `@`. You can check [What character escape sequences are available?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx)

The only option which you have is that if it is in your data then you need to replace it with empty character.